# Partial view inside a View?

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend Framework, is it possible to include (call) a Partial view from within a View?
Cheers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Docs for Partial View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial):

> The Partial view helper is used to render a specified template within its own variable scope. The primary use is for reusable template fragments with which you do not need to worry about variable name clashes. Additionally, they allow you to specify partial view scripts from specific modules.
>
> You would then call it from your view script using the following:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
>     'from' => 'Team Framework',
>     'subject' => 'view partials')); ?>
> ```

If you dont need the separate variable scope, you can simply call `render('script.tpl')` or `include`.

Answer (score -2):

you can do that with the Action View Helper

```
<?php echo $this->action('list','comment'); ?>
```

Where `list` is the action and `comment` is the controller

More details http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Comment: The Action View helper does not render a partial but does a full request to a controller action and then renders that action's view.

Comment: @Gordon but @TurbZ wants to call a view not simply include, so this can be helpful

Comment: the OP wants to include a Partial. There is a helper for that. Using the ActionHelper will make your application run through the entire request lifecycle again each time you call it: bootstrap, routing, dispatch, action execution, delegating to model, rendering view. That's massive overhead. See http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/